# id инициатора события

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, как с помощью jQuery сделать следующее:

HTML

```
<span onclick="sort_menu('up');" id="1_1">UP</span>
<span onclick="sort_menu('down');" id="1_1">DOWN</span>
```

Как написать функцию на jQuery, чтобы по клику на одном из span в функцию передавалось id и "UP или Down"? Количество SPAN'ов много, и попарно у них ID одинаковые.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно параметры хранить в разных атрибутах

```
<span id="1_1" action="up">UP</span>
```

и потом на клике просто их считывать

```
$('span').click(function(){
   var action = $(this).attr('action');
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Можно и не изменять разметку и использовать текущую, ведь параметр и так передается в функции, просто вы его не можете получить, там где написана функция sort_menu, добавьте

```
function sort_menu(paramAction){
теперь можно использовать присланный параметр paramAction = 'up/down'
```

}

**Update:** Id у элементов должен быть уникальным, иначе html-код не будет соответствовать стандартам

Comment: Вот не меняя разметки хотелось бы... **up/down** получается использовать, не получается получить id инициатора.

Comment: да валидность в данном случае мало интересует. В общем тема закрыта, нарыл на просторах паутины. Проблему решил :)

Comment: нужно его передавать вместе с первым параметром, onclick="sort_menu('up','id');"

Comment: Да я это понял, просто видимо неправильно писал. Добавил просто
   `$(this).attr('id')`